# Best way to find active JavaScript code in string of code with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on project, where I am supposed to extract parameter of certain function for use in further logic. Due to limited access, I am only able to get stringified JavaScript script, that user is able to input into the website (yes, safety features are in place). I did not find better solution to this, than to scan that string either by regex, or character by character. But the issue I am facing is, that I need to find out which code is "active" (not commented, not in quotes etc.). I did not want to go down the route of something like (this is only mock):

```js
/* 
for character in string
  if(character === "/")
      if(nextCharacter === *)
          ingore until === star/
      if(nextCharacter === /)
          ignore until \r\n
  else if(character === "`")
      ingore until === `
  else if(character === "'")
      ingore until === '
  else if(character === `"`)
      ingore until === "
*/
```

Because it could stop working/become incomplete with every new version of ES and the solution overall seems too brute forcy and like something that JavaScript might have built in solution for.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Just use a proper parser.

Comment: Use a proper parser. This should work good https://github.com/acornjs/acorn